# C :: Memory access violation randomly appears in Linked List

Tags: c, list, struct, memory-management

so here is the code that gives me headache :

```
void newCopy(ListNode* n, List* l) {
    if (n == NULL) { return; }

    if (n->next == NULL) {
        push(n->data, l);
        return;
    }
    else {
        newCopy(n->next, l);
        push(n->data, l);
        return;
    }
}
```

As you can see if n == NULL then the function is supposed to end but you see it coming : it's not ending the function.

I'm getting "read access violation"  on `if (n->next == NULL)` because n is NULL.
I also get error randomly on other functions, all related to memory access.
The function you should investigate is `State* progDynState(List* taskList)` because everything is done here.

I know some people want minimal reproductible exemple, I can't produce one because everything is used, so here is the entire code.

File Main :

```
#include "Tools.h"
#include <time.h> 

int main()
{
    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand(time(NULL));

    //List creation
    //
    List* taskList = consList();
    Task* task = NULL;
    //Task number
    /*int n = (rand() % 14 + 4);
    //Generate random tasks
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        task = consTask(i + (rand() % 10 + 1) - rand() % 5 , i + (rand() % 10 + 1) - rand() % 5);
        push(task, taskList);
    }*/
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        task = consTask(i,i);
        push(task, taskList);
    }

    std::cout << "Display origin : \n" << listToString_Task(taskList) << " \n";

    //--- CLASSIC ---
    //SOLVE PROBLEM - PROG DYN STATE
    State* opt = progDynState(taskList);


    //--- FPTAS ---
    double sigma = 1; //TO CHANGE DEPENDING ON PRECISION
    //Get deltas 
    double deltaD = findDeltaD(taskList, sigma);
    double deltaL = findDeltaL(taskList, sigma);
    //Rounded values
    List* rL = rounding(taskList, deltaD, deltaL);
    //SOLVE PROBLEM - PROG DYN STATE
    std::cout << "ROUNDED OPT : \n";
    State* roundedOpt = progDynState(rL);
    //Transpose the solution on the original instance
    List* pair = createListTaskPair(taskList, rL);
    State* FPTASopt = transpose(roundedOpt, pair);
    std::cout << "Optimal Solution 2 : \n" << stateToString(FPTASopt) << " \n";
}
```

File ProblemElement.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm> 

#ifndef PROBLEM
#define PROBLEM

// -----------------------------------------------------//
// ------------------ LIST ------------------//
// -----------------------------------------------------//

typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
struct ListNode
{
    void *data;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

typedef struct List List;
struct List
{
    struct ListNode *head;
    struct ListNode *tail;
    int size;
};

//Initialize a list's value
void empty(List* l);

//Create an empty list
List* consList()    //allocate and initialize to NULL values
{
    List* list = (List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List*));
    while(list == NULL) list = (List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List*));
    empty(list);
    return list;
}

//Add data to the head of the list
void push(void *data, List *list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return;
    if (data == NULL) return;
    ListNode *newNode = (ListNode*)calloc(1,sizeof(ListNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = list->head;
    if (list->head == NULL)    //the list is empty
    {
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = list->head;
    }
    else
    {
        list->head = newNode;
    }
    list->size++;
}

//Add data to the tail of the list
void append(void *data, List *list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return;
    if (data == NULL) return;
    ListNode *newNode = (ListNode*)calloc(1,sizeof(ListNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (list->head == NULL)    //the list is empty
    {
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = list->head;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail->next = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
    list->size++;
}

//Remove first element
void pop(List* l) {
    if (l == NULL) return;
    if (l->head->next == NULL) {
        free(l->head);
        empty(l);
    }
    else {
        ListNode* ln = l->head;
        l->head = ln->next;
        free(ln);
    }
    l->size--;
}

void endPop(List* l) {
    if (l == NULL) return;
    if (l->head->next == NULL) {
        pop(l);
    }
    else {
        ListNode* curr = l->head;
        ListNode* prev = NULL;
        while (curr != l->tail) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        free(l->tail);
        prev->next = NULL;
        l->size--;
    }
}

//Remove element contening data
void removeData(void *data, List *list){
    if (data == NULL) return;
    if (list == NULL) return;
    if (list->head == NULL) return;

    //Head to be removed
    if (data == list->head->data) {
        pop(list); 
        return;
    } 
    //Tail to be removed
    if (data == list->tail->data){
        endPop(list);
        return;
    }
    //Other node
    ListNode* curr = list->head;
    ListNode* prev = NULL;
    while (curr->data != data) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    prev->next = curr->next;
    free(curr);
    list->size--;
}

//Make l1's head and tail point to l2's
void assignTo(List* l1, List* l2) {
    if (l1 == NULL) return;
    if (l2 == NULL) return;
    l1->head = l2->head;
    l1->tail = l2->tail;
    l1->size = l2->size;
}

//Initialize a list's value
void empty(List* l) {
    if (l == NULL) return;
    l->head = NULL;
    l->tail = NULL;
    l->size = 0;
}

//Free memory of all nodes
void freeNodes(List* l) {
    if (l == NULL) return;
    if (l->head->next == NULL) {
        pop(l);
        return;
    }
    while (l->head != NULL) {
        pop(l);
    }
}

//Create a copy of n in l with new elements, shared data pointer
void newCopy(ListNode* n, List* l) {
    if (n == NULL) { return; }

    if (n->next == NULL) {
        push(n->data, l);
        return;
    }
    else {
        newCopy(n->next, l);
        push(n->data, l);
        return;
    }
}


// -----------------------------------------------------//
// ------------------ STATE ------------------//
// -----------------------------------------------------//

typedef struct State State;
struct State
{
    double _eOe; //End of execution
    double _t; //Start of next task on first machine
    //First machine
    List* _task1;
    //Second machine
    List* _task2;
};

//Constructor of State
State* consState(double eOe = 0, double t = 0) {
    State* s = (State*)malloc(sizeof(State));
    s->_t = t;
    s->_eOe = eOe;
    s->_task1 = consList();
    s->_task2 = consList();
    return s;
}

//Describe a list of task
std::string listToString_Task(List* tL);

//Describe a state
std::string stateToString(struct State * s) {
    std::string st;
    st += "State : ( t =  " + std::to_string(s->_t) + " , eOe = " + std::to_string(s->_eOe) + " ) \n";
    st += "Task on machine 1 : (" + listToString_Task(s->_task1) + ") \n";
    st += "Task on machine 2 : (" + listToString_Task(s->_task2) + ") \n";
    st += "End of execution : " + std::to_string(s->_eOe);
    return st;
}


// -----------------------------------------------------//
// ------------------ TASK ------------------//
// -----------------------------------------------------//

typedef struct Task Task;
struct Task
{
    double _dur;//task duration
    double _lat;//task latency
};

//Constructor of Task
Task* consTask(double dur = 0, double lat = 0) {
    Task* t = (Task*)malloc(sizeof(Task));
    t->_dur = dur;
    t->_lat = lat;
    return t;
}

//Describe a task
std::string taskToString(struct Task * t) {
    return "Task : ( _dur =  " + std::to_string(t->_dur) + " , _lat = " + std::to_string(t->_lat) + " )";
}


// -----------------------------------------------------//
// ------------------ PAIR : TASK | ROUNDED TASK   ------------------//
// -----------------------------------------------------//

typedef struct TaskPair TaskPair;
struct TaskPair
{
    Task* _origin;//original Tasks
    Task* _rounded;//rounded Tasks
};

//Constructor of TaskPair
TaskPair* consTaskPair(Task* origin, Task* rounded) {
    TaskPair* t = (TaskPair*)malloc(sizeof(TaskPair));
    t->_origin = origin;
    t->_rounded = rounded;
    return t;
}

//Describe a task
std::string taskPairToString(struct TaskPair * t) {
    return "TaskPair : ( origin =  " + taskToString(t->_origin) + " , rounded = " + taskToString(t->_rounded) + " )";
}

#endif // !PROBLEM
```

File Tools.h

```
#pragma once
#include "ProblemElements.h"

#ifndef TOOLS
#define TOOLS

// -----------------------------------------------------//
// ------------------ GENERAL TOOLS ------------------//
// -----------------------------------------------------//

std::string listToString_State(List* sL);
//Keeps only the best state of a PElement<State>.
List* keepBestState(List* sL) {
    if (sL == NULL) return NULL;
    if (sL->head->next == NULL) return sL;
    
    std::cout << "Size : " << std::to_string(sL->size) << "\n";
    std::cout << "sL : " << listToString_State(sL) << "\n";
    State* currS = (State*)sL->head->data;
    State* nextS = (State*)sL->head->next->data;
    //Current element is better, removing following element | Following element is better, removing current element
    if(currS->_eOe <= nextS->_eOe)
        removeData(sL->head->next->data, sL);
    else
        pop(sL);

    return keepBestState(sL);
}

//Split List in two half
void splitList(List* sL, List* half2) {
    //Size of list to sort
    int listSize = sL->size;

    //Half of size list
    if (listSize % 2 == 0) { 
        listSize = listSize / 2;
        sL->size = listSize;
        half2->size = listSize;
    }
    else {
        listSize = (listSize + 1) / 2;
        sL->size = listSize;
        half2->size = listSize-1;
    }

    ListNode* front = sL->head;

    for (int i = 1; i < listSize; i++) 
        front = front->next;

    //Start 2 half
    half2->head = front->next;
    //Cut main list
    front->next = NULL;
    //Set tails
    half2->tail = sL->tail;
    sL->tail = front;
}

//Merge two list of States sorted in increasing order into one list which is in increasing order || Comparing _t value
ListNode* sortedMerge_State(ListNode* a, ListNode* b)
{
    ListNode* result = NULL;

    //BASE CASE
    if (a == NULL)
        return(b);
    if (b == NULL)
        return(a);

    State* state1 = (State*)a->data;
    State* state2 = (State*)b->data;

    //Sort current value
    if (state1->_t <= state2->_t)
    {
        result = a;
        result->next = sortedMerge_State(a->next, b);
    }
    else
    {
        result = b;
        result->next = sortedMerge_State(a, b->next);
    }
    return result;
}//Merge two list of States sorted in increasing order into one list which is in increasing order

//Merge two list of Tasks sorted in decreasing order into one list which is in decreasing order || Comparing _lat value
ListNode* sortedMerge_Task(ListNode* a, ListNode* b)
{
    ListNode* result = NULL;

    if (a == NULL)
        return(b);
    if (b == NULL)
        return(a);

    Task* task1 = (Task*)a->data;
    Task* task2 = (Task*)b->data;

    if (task1->_lat >= task2->_lat)
    {
        result = a;
        result->next = sortedMerge_Task(a->next, b);
    }
    else
    {
        result = b;
        result->next = sortedMerge_Task(a, b->next);
    }
    return result;
}

//Sort a list of States by increasing order || Comparing _t value
void fusionSort_State(List* sL) {
    ListNode* head = sL->head;
    List* half2 = consList();

    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) return;
    //Cut list in two half
    splitList(sL, half2);

    //Recursiv call || Sort the two half
    fusionSort_State(sL);
    fusionSort_State(half2);

    //Merge and sort the sorted halfs
    sL->head = sortedMerge_State(sL->head,half2->head);
    sL->size = sL->size + half2->size;
    for (head = sL->head; head->next != NULL; head = head->next);
    sL->tail = head;
}

//Sort a list of Tasks by decreasing order || Comparing _lat value
void fusionSort_Task(List* sL) {
    ListNode* head = sL->head;
    List* half2 = consList();

    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) return;
    splitList(sL, half2);

    fusionSort_Task(sL);
    fusionSort_Task(half2);

    sL->head = sortedMerge_Task(sL->head,half2->head);
    sL->size = sL->size + half2->size;
    for (head = sL->head; head->next != NULL; head = head->next);
    sL->tail = head;
}

//Removes multiple occurence t
List* removeMultOcc(List* sL) {
    if (sL == NULL) return NULL;
    if (sL->head == NULL) return NULL;
    if (sL->size == 1) return sL;

    fusionSort_State(sL);
    ListNode* curr = sL->head;
    State* state1 = NULL;
    State* state2 = NULL;

    //SIMILAR t
    while (curr != NULL && curr->next != NULL) {
        state1 = (State*)curr->data;
        state2 = (State*)curr->next->data;
        //Current and following element considered as duplicate
        if (state1->_t == state2->_t) {
            //Remove bad duplicate
            if (state1->_eOe <= state2->_eOe)
                removeData(state2, sL);
            else
                removeData(state1, sL);
        }
        //Next duplicate group
        else curr = curr->next;
    }
    return sL;
}

//Summ of _dur
double sumDurTaskList(ListNode* tL) {
    if (tL == NULL) return NULL;
    Task* task = (Task*)tL->data;
    if (tL->next == NULL) return task->_dur;

    return task->_dur + sumDurTaskList(tL->next);
}

//Describe a list of state
std::string listToString_State(List* sL) {
    if (sL == NULL) return "List : [ NOT INITIALIZED ].\n";
    if (sL->size == 0) return "List : [ EMPTY ].\n";
    if (sL->size == 1) return "START OF LIST OF STATE : [ " + stateToString((State*)sL->head->data) + " ]. END OF LIST OF STATE\n";

    ListNode* curr = sL->head;
    std::string st = "START OF LIST OF STATE : [\n ";


    while (curr != NULL) {
        st += stateToString((State*)curr->data);

        if (curr->next != NULL) st += "\n \n";

        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return st + " \n]. END OF LIST OF STATE \n \n \n";
}

//Describe a list of task
std::string listToString_Task(List* tL) {
    if (tL == NULL) return "List : [ NOT INITIALIZED ].\n";
    if (tL->size == 0) return "List : [ EMPTY ].\n";
    if (tL->size == 1) return "START OF LIST OF TASK : [ " + taskToString((Task*)tL->head->data) + " ]. END OF LIST OF TASK\n";

    ListNode* curr = tL->head;
    std::string st = "START OF LIST OF TASK : [ \n";


    while (curr != NULL) {
        st += taskToString((Task*)curr->data);

        if (curr->next != NULL) st += "\n";

        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return st + "\n]. END OF LIST OF TASK\n \n \n";
}

//Describe a list of taskpair
std::string listToString_TaskPair(List* tL) {
    if (tL == NULL) return "List : [ NOT INITIALIZED ].\n";
    if (tL->size == 0) return "List : [ EMPTY ].\n";
    if (tL->size == 1) return "START OF LIST OF TASKPAIR : [ " + taskPairToString((TaskPair*)tL->head->data) + " ]. END OF LIST OF TASKPAIR\n";

    ListNode* curr = tL->head;
    std::string st = "START OF LIST OF TASKPAIR : [ \n";


    while (curr != NULL) {
        st += taskPairToString((TaskPair*)curr->data);

        if (curr->next != NULL) st += "\n";

        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return st + "\n]. END OF LIST OF TASKPAIR\n \n \n";
}


// -----------------------------------------------------//
// ------------------ FPTAS TOOLS ------------------//
// -----------------------------------------------------//

//All Task on machine 2, Tasks sorted by decreasing order of latency 
State* heuristic(List* l) {
    //Copy list to not modify original instance
    List* copyL = consList();
    newCopy(l->head, copyL);
    //Sort by decreasing order
    fusionSort_Task(copyL);

    ListNode* curr = copyL->head;
    Task* currT = (Task*)curr->data;
    //Heuristic's result
    State* H = consState();

    double temp_t = 0;
    double temp_q = 0;
    //Placed Task total duration
    double Ak = 0;

    //Heuristic
    while (curr != NULL) {
        temp_t = Ak / 2 + (currT->_dur / 2);
        temp_q = fmax(temp_t + currT->_lat, H->_eOe);
        H->_eOe = temp_q;
        append(currT, H->_task2);
        Ak += currT->_dur;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return H;
}

//Return the delta value for duration
double findDeltaD(List* l, double sigma) { return (sigma*sumDurTaskList(l->head)) / (4 * l->size); }

//Return the delta value for latency
double findDeltaL(List* l, double sigma) {
    List* copyL = consList();
    newCopy(l->head, copyL);
    return (sigma*heuristic(copyL)->_eOe) / (6 * l->size);
}

//Round duration depending on deltaD and latency depending on deltaL || Create a new list
List* rounding(List* taskList, double deltaD, double deltaL) {
    //Current node
    ListNode* curr = taskList->head;
    //Current task
    Task* currT = NULL;
    //Rounded task
    Task* newT = NULL;
    //Rounded task list
    List* l = consList();

    if (taskList->size == 1) {
        currT = (Task*)curr->data;
        newT = consTask(std::ceil(currT->_dur / deltaD) * deltaD, std::ceil(currT->_lat / deltaL) * deltaL);
        push(newT, l);
        return l;
    }

    while (curr != NULL) {
        currT = (Task*)curr->data;
        newT = consTask(std::ceil(currT->_dur / deltaD) * deltaD, std::ceil(currT->_lat / deltaL) * deltaL);
        append(newT, l);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return l;
}

//Create a new list pairing the corresponding original and rounded Tasks 
List* createListTaskPair(List* origin, List* rounded) {
    //Paired list
    List* pairL = consList();
    ListNode* currO = origin->head;
    ListNode* currR = rounded->head;
    TaskPair* pair = NULL;

    while (currO != NULL) {
        //Create pair
        pair = consTaskPair((Task*)currO->data, (Task*)currR->data);
        //Add pair
        append(pair, pairL);
        //Next value
        currO = currO->next;
        currR = currR->next;
    }

    return pairL;
}

//Transpose Optimal Solution of a rounded instance to it's original instance
State* transpose(State* opt, List* taskPair){
    //Transposed State || result
    State* trueOpt = consState();

    ListNode* currStateTask1 = opt->_task1->head;
    ListNode* currStateTask2 = opt->_task2->head;
    ListNode* currPair = taskPair->head;
    //Placed Task total duration
    double Ak = 0;

    //Transpose Machine 1 Task
    while (currStateTask1 != NULL) {
        //Current Task
        Task* currT = (Task*)currStateTask1->data;
        bool found = false;
        TaskPair* currP = NULL;

        //Search in Pairs
        while (!found) {
            currP = (TaskPair*)currPair->data;
            if (currT == currP->_rounded) found = true;
            else currPair = currPair->next;
        }

        //Add Task to transposed State
        append(currP->_origin, trueOpt->_task1);
        //Add Task duration to _t
        trueOpt->_t += currP->_origin->_dur;
        //Define new _eOe
        trueOpt->_eOe = fmax(trueOpt->_t + currP->_origin->_lat , trueOpt->_eOe);

        //Remove Task to speed up next research
        removeData(currP, taskPair);
        //Reinitialize to head
        currPair = taskPair->head;
        //Next Task to transpose
        currStateTask1 = currStateTask1->next;
    }
    
    //Only Machine 1 execution
    Ak = trueOpt->_t;

    //Transpose Machine 2 Task
    while (currStateTask2 != NULL) {
        //Current Task
        Task* currT = (Task*)currStateTask2->data;
        bool found = false;
        TaskPair* currP = NULL;

        //Search in Pairs
        while (!found) {
            currP = (TaskPair*)currPair->data;
            if (currT == currP->_rounded) found = true;
            else currPair = currPair->next;
        }

        //Add Task to transposed State
        append(currP->_origin, trueOpt->_task2);
        //Define new _eOe
        trueOpt->_eOe = fmax((Ak - trueOpt->_t)/2 + currP->_origin->_dur/2 + currP->_origin->_lat, trueOpt->_eOe);

        //Add curr Task time to Ak
        Ak += currP->_origin->_dur;
        //Remove Task to speed up next research
        removeData(currP, taskPair);
        //Reinitialize to head
        currPair = taskPair->head;
        //Next Task to transpose
        currStateTask2 = currStateTask2->next;
    }

    return trueOpt;
}


// -----------------------------------------------------//
// ------------------ PROG DYN ALGO ------------------//
// -----------------------------------------------------//

//Use Dynamic Programmation based on States to find an Optimal Solution
State* progDynState(List* taskList) {
    std::cout << "PROG DYN | State ==>> \n";
    std::cout << "Task List :: \n" << listToString_Task(taskList) << "\n";

    //Get-through list
    ListNode * currT = taskList->head;

    //Start state, (0 , 0 , 0 , 0)
    State* start = consState();
    //State list
    List* sL = consList(); //Xi-1
    push(start, sL);
    List* sL2 = consList();//Xi
    //Get through list
    ListNode* currS = sL->head;
    //Placed Task total duration
    double Ak = 0;

    while (currT != NULL) {
        Task* ctask = (Task*)currT->data;
        empty(sL2);

        //Create new States with new Task and old States
        while (currS != NULL) {
            State* cstate = (State*)currS->data;
            //std::cout << "MM |||| MM - Mother State : " << stateToString(cstate) << "\n\n";
            //ON MACHINE 1
            //new start, start of state + task duration
            double temp_t = cstate->_t + ctask->_dur;
            //max between (start of state + latency of task) and (end of original state) 
            double temp_q = fmax(temp_t + ctask->_lat, cstate->_eOe);
            State * s1 = consState(temp_q, temp_t);
            //Keep track of tasks on first machine
            newCopy(cstate->_task1->head, s1->_task1);
            append(currT->data, s1->_task1);
            //Keep track of tasks on second machine
            newCopy(cstate->_task2->head, s1->_task2);
            //std::cout << "S1 |||| S1 - State 1 : " << stateToString(s1) << "\n\n";
            //Add state to list
            push(s1, sL2);

            //ON MACHINE 2
            //new start, start of state + task duration
            temp_t = (Ak - cstate->_t) / 2 + (ctask->_dur / 2);
            //max between (start of state + latency of task) and (end of original state) 
            temp_q = fmax(temp_t + ctask->_lat, cstate->_eOe);
            State * s2 = consState(temp_q, cstate->_t);
            //Keep track of tasks on second machine
            newCopy(cstate->_task2->head, s2->_task2);
            append(currT->data, s2->_task2);
            //Keep track of tasks on first machine
            newCopy(cstate->_task1->head, s2->_task1);
            //std::cout << "S2 |||| S2 - State 2 : " << stateToString(s2) << "\n\n";
            //Add state to list
            push(s2, sL2);

            //Next list member
            currS = currS->next;
        }
        //Xi CREATED

        //ERASE OLD SET OF STATE --- Xi-1
        freeNodes(sL);
        //SET IT ANEW --- Xi-1 = Xi
        assignTo(sL, sL2);
        //OPTIMIZATION
        //Removes multiple occurence of t value, only keeping the best of each.
        sL = removeMultOcc(sL);
        //Keeps best state
        //sL = keepBestState(sL);
        currS = sL->head;
        //END OF OPTIMIZATION
        //Add curr Task time to Ak
        Ak += ctask->_dur;
        //Next list member
        currT = currT->next;
    }

    //std::cout << "Best States : \n" << listToString_State(sL) << " \n\n";

    sL = keepBestState(sL);

    std::cout << "Optimal Solution : \n" << stateToString((State*)sL->head->data) << " \n";

    return (State*)sL->head->data;
}

#endif // !TOOLS
```

What is wrong with my code ?

It seems like something is bad in my memory management but I can't find where. I thank you greatly for your help !
I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Did you try to debug this with the Visual Studio debugger, which is very powerful and very easy to use?

Comment: Start with the smallest input set possible to replicate the error, then use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement to make sure it really does what you think it should do. This is of course helped if you had less code to debug, so also try to scale back the code itself to the smallest possible program that replicates the error. Worst case, start over with an empty `main` function, and add the rest in steps, building (with verbose warnings) and testing in between the steps. Each step should be as small as possible.

Comment: @Pouillaude Alexis  This call of calloc is incorrect List* list = (List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List*)); You need to use sizeof( List ) instead of sizeof( List * )

Comment: @Pouillaude Alexis And if you are using std::string then why is the target C and not C++?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow My teacher want all the algorithm part of the project to be in C and I find std such as string and iostream really useful to display things. That's why. I would have wrote the entire code in C++ if I could ^^

Comment: I couldn't analyze all your code... One problem I found: `(List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List*));` probably should be `(List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List));` unless you actually need a pointer to list... and isn't it actually be also tagged C++?

Comment: @Pranavappu yeah I understand, there is a lot of it. Somebody already pointed that out and it was a mistake, `(List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List));` is what I wanted. And the answer to "Why C++ ?" is just above ^^ EDIT : you said tagged, my bad, it's just that 99.9% of my code is C. As I said earlier, i only use C++ to display results.

Comment: What did you exactly mean here?
`
 `List* list = (List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List));`
    `while(list == NULL) list = (List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List));`
`
The first one creates a list.. So why do you need the second line? Is it to keep asking OS until a valid address is given? I haven't seen allocation functions failing.. so that's why I'm asking.